# testing controllers requiring login

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm learning PHPUnit and I want to testing page witch requiring login (like change your password, add a new article, etc). Normal test look like this

```
$response = $this->get('/');

 $response->assertStatus(200);
```

But if page requires authentication (is intended for logged in users), it won't work. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: you probably need mock user, take a look at this https://medium.com/yish/how-to-mock-authentication-user-on-unit-test-in-laravel-1441d491d82c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "act as" a user while running tests with Laravel

```php
$user = \App\User::find(1) //replace with creating or finding the user you want
$this->actingAs($user);
```